# How to print all possible lines that are not included in the input?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, command-line

I have a text file where each line looks like this:

```
a_1/b_1/c_1
a_2/b_2/c_2
a_3/b_3/c_3
...
```

and where a_n, b_n and c_n can be any number from M to N. For example, M=1 and N=10 and my input file contains the following data:

```
1/2/3
1/4/2
1/4/10
1/5/2
2/2/1
2/3/4
```

What I want is to print all possible lines that are not included in the input:

```
1/1/1
1/1/2
1/1/3
...
1/1/10
1/2/1
1/2/2
1/2/4
...
1/2/10
1/3/1
...
1/3/10
1/4/1
1/4/3
...
1/4/9
1/5/1
1/5/3
...
1/10/9
1/10/10
2/1/1
...
2/1/10
2/2/1
...
2/3/3
2/3/5
...
10/10/9
10/10/10
```

What tool should I use (I'd prefer to use AWK if possible), and which way should I choose to solve this task?

Comment: Do you want the `a_`, `b_` and `c_` or just the numbers not already found after the `a_`, `b_` and `c_` (which is what you show, but it is unclear if that is just short-hand) -- or or the `a_`, `b_` and `c_` just used to show there are `3` numbers?

Comment: @David: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by `a_`, `b_` and `c_`? I used underscores to represent [mathematical subscripts](http://orgmode.org/manual/Subscripts-and-superscripts.html), so a_1 = a₁. In the first line of my example, a₁=1, b₁ = 2, c₁=3.

Comment: I figured it out. You were just using the `abc` for example references. It was unclear when you said `"I have an input file..."` with `a_1/b_1/c_1...`

Comment: `grep -vf test <(echo "$(printf "%s\n" {1..10}/{1..10}/{1..10})")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v m=1 -v n=10 '{
    a[$1]
}
END{
    for ( i=m; i<=n;i++){
        for( j=m; j<=n;j++){
            for( k=m; k<=n;k++){
                p=i"/"j"/"k;
                if (!( p in a )){
                    print p
                }
            }
        }
    }
}' file
```

Where `file` will have the entries to omit from the output.

Comment: I did not test this yet, but there are some things that I don't understand... Why don't you specify field separator? Why `$1`, not `$0`? You put only the first field in `a`? I need some time to test this...

Comment: @lyricallywicked it should be `$0`

Comment: Since space is the field separator $0 and $1 holds same content.

Comment: Yes, it worked as I expected! I accept this answer, because it uses AWK and deals with a minimal amount of files (just 2, not 3, as in `grep`-based solutions).

Answer (score 2):

If you generate a file with the complete set of numbers

```
1/1/1
1/1/2
1/1/3
...
1/1/10
1/2/1
1/2/2
1/2/3
1/2/4
...
```

in model.txt (f.e.)

you can do it with a single command:

```
 grep -v -f model.txt input.txt >> output.txt
```

UPDATE:

To create the model.txt file you can do this:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
        for j in {1..10}
        do
                for l in {1..10}
                do
                        echo $i/$j/$l >> model.txt
                done
        done
done
```

Comment: And how would you generate `model.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

You should generate a file with all possible input, then give the following command:

```
`grep -v -f <allpossibleinput> < <yourinput>`
```

Comment: The file with all possible inputs is used as a file with patterns (-f flag). All values in your input file are matched against it. That would just print all your input, but with the -v flag it prints the inverse of that: all entries that did not match the lines in all possible inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you like slow brute force approaches, you can use loops in bash (this isn't good for large number ranges -- anything over ~10 is better done in `awk` or using the `grep -f` solutions). However, this does provide output is correct numerical sort order due to whole-word matching:

```
#!/bin/bash

test -z "$1" -o -z "$2" -o -z "$3" && { ## validate 3 args
    printf "error: insufficient input, usage: %s M N\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

test "$1" -eq "$1" >/dev/null 1>&2 || { ## validate 1st is int
    printf "error: invalid input, %s is not an integer\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

test "$2" -eq "$2" >/dev/null 1>&2 || { ## validate 2nd is int
    printf "error: invalid input, %s is not an integer\n" "$2"
    exit 1
}

test -r "$3" || { ## validate 3rd is input file
    printf "error: invalid input, file '%s' not readable\n" "$3"
    exit 1
}

## for all i/j/k not found in input, output i/j/k
for ((i = $1; i <= $2; i++)); do
    for ((j = $1; j <= $2; j++)); do
        for ((k = $1; k <= $2; k++)); do
            grep -qw "$i/$j/$k" "$3" &>/dev/null || echo "$i/$j/$k"
        done
    done
done
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/3num.txt
1/2/3
1/4/2
1/4/10
1/5/2
2/2/1
2/3/4
```

**Example Output**

```
$ bash missing3.sh 1 10 dat/3num.txt
...
1/2/1
1/2/2
1/2/4
...
1/3/10
1/4/1
1/4/3
1/4/4
1/4/5
1/4/6
1/4/7
1/4/8
1/4/9
1/5/1
1/5/3
...
```

You will want to use another solution that does not embed `grep` in a nested loop, as it is slow, but for small ranges it's not bad.

(with slight modification, you can use this to generate the 'all possible inputs' file to use with `grep -f`)